# WebView App with back gesture navigation in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have been working on building a WebView app with back gesture navigation in SwiftUI for iOS. I am a beginner with SwiftUI.

I have built the WebView part and it opens just fine. The problem starts when I try to move back to the previous page using gestures. I have tried various things but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
        webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds)
        webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
}
```

The gestureRecognizer isn't detecting that I would like to go back to the previous page.

I would appreciate any advice. Thank you very much!!